# Exception when passing value from scanner

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I ma getting Exception  when trying type from keyboard 2nd scanner in "talis probability". Mainly i am trying to change from keyboard probabilty of tail..

```
 Number of threads: 2
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:862)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextFloat(Scanner.java:2345)
    at rzutmoneta.Toss.main(Toss.java:32)
talis probability: Java Result: 1
```

and dont know why...but i know that issue is probably  here "final class  Coin".. How to repair my program?

```
final class Toss {
 public static float p;

  public static void main(String... argv) {


    System.out.print("Number of threads: ");
    int how_much;
    try (Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in)) {
      how_much = input.nextInt();
    }

    System.out.print("talis probability: ");

    try (Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in)) {
      p = input.nextFloat();
    }

    ExecutorService threads = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors());
    for (int i = 0; i < how_much; ++i)
      threads.submit(Toss::run);
    threads.shutdown();
  }

  private static void run() {
    Coin coin = new Coin();
    int count = 0;
    while (coin.flip() == Coin.UpDown.Tails) {
      System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + ": Talis!");
      ++count;
    }
    System.out.printf("%s: heads! %d talis%n", Thread.currentThread().getName(), count);
  }

}

final class  Coin {
   public static float p;

    Coin() {
         Toss.p = Coin.p;
    }

  enum UpDown {
    Heads, Tails
   }

  UpDown flip() {

    //return ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextBoolean() ? Strony.Orzeł : Strony.Reszka;
    return ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextFloat() < p ? UpDown.Heads : UpDown.Tails;  
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using this code:

```
try (Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in)) {
  how_much = input.nextInt();
}
```

You are using the auto-closing feature of the [***try-with-resources***](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) syntax of Java. The Scanner gets a call to `close()`, which closes the underlying `System.in`, so creating a new Scanner the next time on `System.in` doesn't work, because `System.in` is closed.

Instead create one scanner and use it for every interaction with the user on the command line.

Comment: Does that make me a noob ? :P Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in); p = in.nextFloat(); , now works great. Thank u for getting new knowledge.